# Hashes and Arrays with redis

Tags: ruby, redis

Suppose I wanted to store a `hash` containing an `array`:

```
{:foo=>[:bar, :baz], :quack => 'duck'}
```

At first glance I have 2 options.

1. Serialize the value of `:foo` and store it it as a `string`.
2. Convert the value to a `set`, store a `hash` with the `key` of the `set`, and rebuild my data structure with 2 queries, for the `set` and the `hash` respectively.

The second approach feels messy to me, especially considering the possibility of a `hash` or multiple `hash`'es being nested within the `array` **and** the work involved rebuilding that structure upon retrieval.

What is the best approach for storing complex data structures with `redis`?

Is there a better option then the options I've listed that would allow me to take advantage of `redis` data types?

Comment: I can't tell you the best approach. I CAN tell you i have always serialized my data as json and stored it as a string in redis. and to the question, no, redis is simple key value with limited data types. option 1 imho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not sharing the data with other objects, you should just go ahead and serialise them.

...As long as they are under 512MB